question: quel est l'adjectif associé au verbe s'empresser
Quels sont l'adjectif et le substantif dérivés du verbe « s'empresser »?
Le mot que je cherche correspond partiellement à eager et eagerness mais plutot péjoratif.
Imaginons un groupe de malfaiteurs dont l'un s'empresse le plus, prend l'initiative, est le plus audacieux. Qu'utiliseriez-vous pour décrire cette personne ?

« L'empressement de cette personne pour faire face à un problème est hallucinant !!  » — «  Empressé comme il est, il va battre tous les records ».   L'adverbe ou le participe passé conviennent, mais ce n'est pas le mot idoine dans un contexte de malfrats,

S'empresse le plus ... à faire quoi?

Je ne vois pas ce que "empressé", le participe employé adjectivement, a d'insatisfaisant: est-ce parce que "s'empresser" est un peu désuet au sens "développer beaucoup d'énergie", ayant développé la connotation "brasser beaucoup d'air"?
S'il faut éviter de joindre l'inefficacité à l'empressement, il est possible à la place de faire preuve de {zèle | enthousiasme | affairement}; l'adjectif correspondant est
{zélé | enthousiaste | affairé}.
Si l'accent est plus sur la rouerie des malfrats ou sur la perversité de leurs plans que sur leur dépense d'énergie, il y a aussi "machiavélisme" et l'adjectif associé "machiavélique".
Un exemple d'utilisation un peu plus étoffé de "empressé" (même non grammatical), ou en anglais de "eager", aiderait certainement à clarifier le problème.

Le mot que je cherche [...] (est) plutot péjoratif. Imaginons un groupe de malfaiteurs dont l'un s'empresse le plus, prend l'initiative, est le plus audacieux. Qu'utiliseriez-vous pour décrire cette personne ?
Je l'appellerais le meneur. Pour l'adjectif, ça depend de la phrase, (em)pressé peut-être, ou avide.

I would call him le meneur. Not sure about which adjective to choose, that would depend on the sentence. (Em)pressé might work, or avide maybe.

Je me demande s'il n'y a pas une confusion de la part de l'OP sur le sens de s'empresser. dont l'un s'empresse le plus, qui prend l'initiative me paraît un peu bizarre. Je ne connecterais pas eager et s'empresser.

D'habitude, on s'empresse de faire quelque chose (de spécifique), non? Je ne dirais pas de quelqu'un qu'il est "empressé" ou qu'il "s'empresse" pour dénoter un trait de caractère, mais l'OP semble utiliser le mot dans ce sens.

@Frank La langue maternelle de l'OP est le chinois. Ceci explique certainement les interrogations qu'on peut avoir sur la compréhension des sens respectifs d'empresser et d'eager.

@Frank Je ne me suis pas trop attaché à s'empresser ou à la question du titre. J'ai surtout répondu à l'interrogation sur un substantif qui correspondrait à la description présente dans le corps de la question. J'ai clarifié ça dans ma réponse.

Mais la réponse pourrait laisser entendre que empressé convient pour décrire un trait de caractère - ce sens du mot empressé est au moins très vieilli, si ce n'est inexistant dans la langue courante?
